# How to see what font is being used on a website when it’s not directly in the html?

Tags: html, css, fonts

How do I know what font is being used to make “MAPLE SYRUP” here?

I opened the page source, but I see no fonts being used. It’s a beautiful font I’d love to use. I believe it has something to do with css, but I haven’t been able to figure out where the css code is if that’s where this font is specified.

I am very green at web stuff. Also, how do I tell if this is an open use font or a proprietary font?

https://runamokmaple.com/

```
<li>
1012
<div class="smm-mega-menu">
1013
<div class="smm-row"><div class="smm-span-3"><aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><div class="menu-maple-syrup-container"><ul id="menu-maple-syrup" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-8295" class="menu-header menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8295"><a href="https://runamokmaple.com/shop/maple-syrup/">MAPLE SYRUP</a></li>
```

I’d prefer an answer that works on mobile iPhone if possible.

Comment: I believe the font is called `Avenir Next`. I use [Fonts Ninja](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fonts-ninja/eljapbgkmlngdpckoiiibecpemleclhh) to identify these but that is just one of many options.

Comment: It can be purchased here if you are curious. [myfonts font store link](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/avenir-next-pro-font-linotype?rfsn=6624850.7d2250)

Comment: Be a bit cautious when trying to find out exactly what font is being used. For example, on my Windows10 Edge system using the browser's devtools inspect facility I can see that body has several fonts listed - Avenir and various flavors of Helvetica etc). But these aren't actually loaded on the system. What OS/browser/device are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth the good thing about webfonts is that they don't need to be actually installed on the system to be used. In this particular case Avenir Next is used, can also be seen in the browsers network tab.

Comment: @cloned - interesting - I didn't see it being loaded at all. And if I removed that font-family setting and used just sans-serif the visual appearance was exactly the same. Not sure what I'm missing here!

Comment: @AHaworth it is not loaded if you block loading of fonts or blocked the server entirely. But since this is a custom user setting, that's why there are fallback fonts defined. If you have a default system without any restrictions it will load the font and display it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don’t have such restrictions. Did you find where the font source was defined?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the element, inspect it. Filter the CSS properties in the styles tab e.g. by typing `font-family`, and there it is.

`font-family: avenir next,Arial,sans-serif;`

Answer (score 0):

After running this code, the result will be copied to the clipboard. You can paste the result into any text editor to view it.

```
var ret = {};
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
elements.forEach(function (element) {
  var font = {
    fontFamily: getComputedStyle(element).fontFamily,
    fontWeight: getComputedStyle(element).fontWeight,
    fontStyle: getComputedStyle(element).fontStyle
  };

  var fontKey = font.fontFamily + ':' + font.fontWeight + ':' + font.fontStyle;
  if (ret[fontKey]) {
    ret[fontKey].count++;
  } else {
    ret[fontKey] = {
      font: font,
      count: 1
    };
  }
});

var resultString = '';
Object.values(ret).forEach(function (item) {
  var font = item.font;
  var count = item.count;

  resultString += 'Font: ' + font.fontFamily + '\n';
  resultString += 'Weight: ' + font.fontWeight + '\n';
  resultString += 'Style: ' + font.fontStyle + '\n';
  resultString += 'Count: ' + count + '\n\n';
});

console.log(resultString);

var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.value = resultString;
document.body.appendChild(textarea);

textarea.select();
textarea.setSelectionRange(0, textarea.value.length);

document.execCommand('copy');

document.body.removeChild(textarea);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Finding the `font-family` of a Particular Text

The OP question is<sup>✤</sup>:

> *"How do I know what font is being used to make “MAPLE SYRUP” [here](https://runamokmaple.com/)?"*

<sup>✤Embedded link is mine</sup>

The answer by [Bill Fransen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089495/2813224)<sup>✣</sup> is correct but lacks details for novices and [Mikhail Chernysh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597357/2813224)<sup>✲</sup> answer is useful but lacks any explanation and doesn't pinpoint exactly what font *"MAPLE SYRUP"* was rendered in.

<sup>✣ See **Method 1**</sup>
<sup>✲ See **Method 2**</sup>

### Method 1

#### Using the Developer Tools in the Browser.

The following example is a short slideshow using Chrome. The HTML and JavaScript is just for demonstration purposes. Review it in full page mode.

```js
$(".bx").bxSlider();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">

<main class="bx">
  <section>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/n0V40Wq/inspect.png">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/jGXqn7k/developertools.png">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6NMn7Gx/stylestab.png">
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hZM3N5d/computedtab.png">
  </section>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

### Method 2

#### Using JavaScript

In this example, the font used to render the text is from [fontCDN.com](https://www.cdnfonts.com/) (like Google Fonts). I couldn't find a font CDN that had the font *Avenir Next* so I settled for [*Avenir*](https://www.cdnfonts.com/avenir.font). You can still [download the files](https://freefontsfamily.com/avenir-next-font-download-free/) and host them yourself.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/**
* It finds the CSS propertyValues of each propertyName given that is
* computed on a given DOM Object (HTMLElement) or pseudo-element (CSS `::selector`).
* @param {Object<DOM>} node - HTMLElement referenced as a DOM Object.
* @param {String<selector>} pseudoElement - Pseudo-element of node, if there is none, 
*                                           null is required.
* @param {Array<spread>} properties - One or more CSS propertyNames.
* @returns {Object} - An Object literal -- each propertyName of properties 
*                     is a key and it's corresponding propertyValue is 
*                     assigned as it's value.
*/  
const findStyles = (node, pseudoElement, ...properties) => {
  const cS = getComputedStyle(node, pseudoElement);
  const aA = properties.map(prop => {
    let pV = cS.getPropertyValue(prop);
    return [prop, pV];
  });
  return Object.fromEntries(aA);
}

const foot = document.querySelector("footer");

const fS = findStyles(foot, null, "font-family", "font-size", "line-height");

console.log(JSON.stringify(fS));
```

```css
/**
 * Alternate method to access CDNFonts
 */


/* @import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/avenir');
 */

:root {
  font: 2.25ch/1.15 'Avenir';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    Primary method to access CDNFonts
  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/avenir" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- 
    Inline CSS goes inside <style> 
         ↙️  -->
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  &lt;HEADER&gt;
  <header>
    <h1>&lt;H1&gt; Masthead</h1>
    <p>&lt;P&gt; Deck</p>
  </header>
  &lt;MAIN&gt;
  <main>
    <h2>&lt;H2&gt; Headline</h2>
    <p>&lt;P&gt; Subhead</p>
    &lt;ARTICLE&gt;
    <article>
      <p>&lt;P&gt; Copy</p>
    </article>
  </main>
  &lt;FOOTER&gt;
  <footer>
    <address>
    &lt;ADDRESS&gt; <a href="mailto:zer00ne@null.net">&lt;A&gt; Email zer00ne</a>
   </address>
  </footer>
  <!-- 
    It's common practice to place all <script>s before the
    closing </body> tag.
    Load external JavaScript before the inline JavaScript 
  -->
  <script src="https://website.com/path/to/script.js"></script>
  <!-- 
    Inline JavaScript goes inside <script> 
          ↙️   -->
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```